# What causes Spring scheduler to execute before the application and servlet starts up?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I have a simple Spring-Boot web application with some scheduling tasks:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder app) {
        return app.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And a service executing two scheduling tasks:

```
@Service
public class SchedulingService {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 15000)
    private void first() {
        // log first
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 6000)
    public void second() {
        // log second
    }
}
```

Is there any explanation revealing why one of the scheduling tasks has been executed before the application and servlet starts up? This happens repeatedly and the log order is always the same, so I suspect the multithreading doesn't take place - there is nearly one-second difference between the first and the second scheduling task.

Here is the log with `highlighted parts of the scheduling task log`:

> 2018-08-18 20:47:53.085  INFO 251168 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page template: index
>
> 2018-08-18 20:47:53.300  INFO 251168 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
>
> 2018-08-18 20:47:53.314  INFO 251168 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.a.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : No TaskScheduler/ScheduledExecutorService bean found for scheduled processing
>
> `2018-08-18 20:47:53.321 HERE LOGGED FIRST`
>
> 2018-08-18 20:47:53.344  INFO 251168 --- [ost-startStop-1] my.appname.Application            : Started Application in 5.565 seconds (JVM running for 16.93)
>
> 2018-08-18 20:47:53.396  INFO 251168 --- [           main] org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProtocol     : Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
>
> 2018-08-18 20:47:53.400  INFO 251168 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina     : Server startup in 15970 ms
>
> 2018-08-18 20:47:53.477  INFO 251168 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/Rattle]        : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
>
> 2018-08-18 20:47:53.477  INFO 251168 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
>
> 2018-08-18 20:47:53.520  INFO 251168 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 43 ms
>
> `2018-08-18 20:47:54.103  HERE LOGGED SECOND`
>
> `2018-08-18 20:47:59.335  HERE LOGGED SECOND`
>
> `2018-08-18 20:48:05.334  HERE LOGGED SECOND`
>
> `2018-08-18 20:48:08.334 HERE LOGGED FIRST`

Comment: If all its dependencies are satisfied the bean is created. As there is no delay, the task runs immediately. Why would it wait for startup if you didn't tell it to?

Comment: @BoristheSpider: I wonder if the scheduling task can be executed before the Spring application starts itself: `my.appname.Application : Started Application in 5.565 seconds`. Isn't the scheduling bean dependant on the application start. Or do I understand this log wrong or miss something?

Comment: @BoristheSpider how to tell it to wait until the application starts up ?
Sorry for commenting on old question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just created an empty SpringBoot project, added your class and tried to reproduce the same issue.
On SpringBoot `2.0.4.RELEASE` I see that both tasks run at the same time and same thread:

```
2018-08-18 21:16:54.145  INFO 10239 --- [pool-1-thread-1] com.test.SchedulingService               : LOG FIRST
2018-08-18 21:16:54.145  INFO 10239 --- [pool-1-thread-1] com.test.SchedulingService               : LOG SECOND
```

Then, I added a `Thread.sleep(100)` on the both tasks as I cannot predict the execution order.

```
2018-08-18 21:21:14.775  INFO 10274 --- [pool-1-thread-1] com.test.SchedulingService               : LOG FIRST
2018-08-18 21:21:14.878  INFO 10274 --- [pool-1-thread-1] com.test.SchedulingService               : LOG SECOND
```

The delay of aprox 100ms between the log entries, confirm that they run on the same thread.

You might think that setting the `initialDelay = 0` on the `@Scheduled` might help, but it will not; everything will still be on the main thread.

The solution I found is defining a custom bean that creates a `customTaskScheduler`:

```
@Bean()
public  ThreadPoolTaskScheduler  taskScheduler(){
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    taskScheduler.setPoolSize(2);
    taskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("Async-");
    return  taskScheduler;
}
```

Now, the logs show that both tasks are executed at the same time and by different threads:

```
2018-08-18 21:30:26.482  INFO 10383 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-08-18 21:30:26.486  INFO 10383 --- [           main] com.test.ProjectApplication              : Started ProjectApplication in 1.767 seconds (JVM running for 2.137)
2018-08-18 21:30:26.555  INFO 10383 --- [        Async-2] com.test.SchedulingService               : LOG SECOND
2018-08-18 21:30:26.555  INFO 10383 --- [        Async-1] com.test.SchedulingService               : LOG FIRST
```

I defined a thread pool of `size = 2`. What will happen if I have 3 tasks to run? One of the tasks will need to wait to complete the execution of the previous 2, get the thread released and check the execution queue again.

```
2018-08-18 21:33:48.895  INFO 10412 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-08-18 21:33:48.899  INFO 10412 --- [           main] com.test.ProjectApplication              : Started ProjectApplication in 1.888 seconds (JVM running for 2.258)
2018-08-18 21:33:48.960  INFO 10412 --- [        Async-1] com.test.SchedulingService               : LOG FIRST
2018-08-18 21:33:48.960  INFO 10412 --- [        Async-2] com.test.SchedulingService               : LOG SECOND
2018-08-18 21:33:49.065  INFO 10412 --- [        Async-2] com.test.SchedulingService               : LOG THIRD
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, but I was able to get around it by specifying the `cron` parameter instead of using `fixedRate` or `fixedRateString` like so `@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 4 ? * SUN,THU")`

More details on using the cron expression in spring-boot can be found here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronExpression.html